# Flask use Session value can be copied to another computer and used. Is this ok?

Tags: python, security, session, browser, flask

I'm fairly new to Flask, but I like it so far.  I am using the method described in the flask.pocoo.org quickstart guide:

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return 'Logged in as %s' % escape(session['username'])
    return 'You are not logged in'
```

Anyways, this works great, but I am concerned with the following.  If I login, I can copy the value of the cookie, bring that value to another computer, and insert them into a newly created cookie on that computer and I am logged in.

1) Is this a legit use case, or is this hard for attackers to do?  Obviously not copy and paste, but to get access to that cookie value...

2) Do you know of any good ways prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes down to it, HTTP is an inherently stateless protocol. So you really only have two choices for authenticating a client over time:

- Force the client to authenticate every time it makes a request. This is not only inconvenient, but also requires the client to send their authentication credentials (username/password/etc..) for every request to the server.
- Send the client an authentication token they can store and use for future requests within the session. This is usually done with cookies but in theory, could be stored and sent back to the server in different ways.

Now, I'm not saying cookies are entirely secure - some things you'll want to watch out for are to make sure you're using HTTPS, and XSS/CSRF:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Security

but the issues you appear to be concerned about aren't as big a deal as they might seem. To answer your questions directly:

1) It's not really a "legit use case". Stealing someone's cookie is the equivalent of stealing their login session. It's difficult for an attacker to steal a cookie and it typically requires a vulnerability in your site.

2) There's no way to prevent someone from logging in as you if they have your login cookie. But if you're concerned about cookies in particular, you can consider token-based authentication:

https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/

Keep in mind though that, even in this paradigm, there's still an authentication token that can be used to login as the user if it gets stolen by an attacker.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Youssef.  I thought that it might not be a legit use case, but it helps to hear it from someone else.  I will start looking at tokens, but knowing that what I am doing is still secure reduces the urgency.